# Exact differential equation identity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I was looking at the solution to exact differential equations, and in the solution it states that if,

$$\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x} = M(x,y)$$

and,

$$\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} = N(x,y)$$

Then it is implied that,

$$dg(x,y) = M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy$$

How does the last equation follow from the other two?

Comment: This is an example of a total differential/total derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find derivatives more palatable than differentials, so imagine dividing your equation by $dt$:

$$\frac{dg(x,y)}{dt} = M(x,y)\frac{dx}{dt} + N(x,y)\frac{dy}{dt}$$

If you substitute in your expressions, you get
$$\frac{dg(x,y)}{dt} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$$

which is the chain rule for multiple variables.